# Plot sklearn RandomForestRegressor MSE

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

Does anyone know of a way to plot the MSE of the trees from the random forest regressor in sklearn?

In R this is incredibly easy:

```
> fit = randomForest(y ~ X)
> plot(fit)
```

but I haven't found of a way to do this in python.

Comment: What exactly do you want to plot. The MSE on the training data? That is a single point, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

mean_squared_error(y, predictions)
```

or using numpy:

```
np.mean((y_test - est.predict(X_test))**2)
```